# Idle SSH connection gets reset in ubuntu 20.04 WSL (Windows10)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssh, putty, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using ubuntu wsl on windows10. I use it to ssh into remote VMs on my corporate network. **I can successfully ssh to VMs.**

**BUT** If I leave it unattended for some time, the ssh connection automatically gets disconnected with this message:

`client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer`

Earlier I used puTTY to ssh into remote machines and the puTTY session would never terminate even if I left the session idle for days. I think it was because of this puTTY connection setting `Seconds between keepalives (0 to turn off)` being set to `0`

How can achieve the same in ubuntu wsl. I have tried adding `ConnectTimeout 0` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` but it did not work.

Comment: I have this same issue, except it literally happens in the middle of doing things. It takes a few hours but I will always get that message... Only happens with WSL. Frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall look on these parameters on the client side `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
`ServerAliveInterval`
`ServerAliveCountMax`

Maybe you can try set and elaborate from there about the timeout.
`ServerAliveInterval 60`

Reference Ubuntu [ssh_config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/ssh_config.5.html)

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue with a slightly different setup: SSH from Windows Terminal (PowerShell) to an Ubuntu Server which is a VirtualBox virtual machine. If I left the connection running overnight, I was greeted in the morning with:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
```

There wasn't a `by peer` in that line by the way, just the above. I fixed it by changing the server config only. At the Ubuntu shell:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Added the following:
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 5
```

These values can be tweaked of course, but now the connection stays even after the computer goes to sleep or standby.

Answer (score -1):

I get "client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset" shortly after connecting to an Ubuntu machine from Windows 10, even with the firewall turned off.  Two other windows 10 machines don't have this problem.  I even set ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 5 as suggested.  Also got rid of the .ssh contents on Windows 10 as suggested in another forum.  No error messages in /var/log files.  The session shows it is still logged in on the Ubuntu machine.  The Windows 10 machine with the problem ssh'es to other Ubuntu machines with no problem.  Any more suggestions??

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Provide this as a comment to the original post and not an answer. Answers on SO should be intended to provide a potential solution to the original poster's question. This is just another form of +1 which can be helpful if new context is provided as a comment and not as an answer.